# MS Report (rdlc) change body size

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting, rdlc

I need help to change the size of the body in a rdlc report. I cannot find anything to set the body size to A4. I selected A4 option in the report properties, but nothing changed. My only option was to manually change its sizes. Does anybody know how can I do this? Im finding rdlc interface pretty hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You don't set the "body" size to A4, you set the "Report" outer-most level for the report.  The overall PAGE of the report may default to the 8 1/2 by 11, but you can change that.  Then the body will stretch and fill content to the allowed page size.

Comment: Well, I changed the body manually and drag all the textboxes I needed, then, when I needed to print, I notice that I had 4 pages.. So, I had to manually change the body size using the rules. Its really tedious, I just cant think that MS havent thinked of that.

Comment: @Andres, actually, I'm sure it was intentional this way, and there's probably some setting somewhere...  To allow for an "unlimited" length to allow for web-based output where a user can just keep scrolling without having to pay attention to "which physical page".

Comment: Do I have to keep doing what I have been doing?